# Nested PER_METHOD inside PER_CLASS should call TestInstanceFactory

Tags: junit, cdi, weld, junit5, cdi-unit

Currently I am trying to integrate JUnit5.3.0-RC1 into a Weld-SE-Testframework ejb-cdi-unit.

The first solution on JUnit5.2.0 available in ejb-cdi-unit:1.1.15 restricts the TestInstance-Classes somewhat concerning CDI. I can only allow @Inject. That helps already very much, but [see](https://github.com/1and1/ejb-cdi-unit#junit5)

Now trying to implement the TestInstanceFactory, to avoid the mentioned restrictions, I encounter problems with [example](https://github.com/1and1/ejb-cdi-unit/blob/master/examples/ex1-1entity5/src/test/java/com/oneandone/ejbcdiunit/example1_5/ServiceTest5.java).

You can see a Testclass *ServiceTest5* working in Lifecycle **PER_CLASS** and two nested inner classes of which one is working in Lifecycle **PER_METHOD**.

The innerclasses are currently disabled to avoid mails from travis-ci.

I would expect, that before the method *ServiceTest5#WhenSomeEntitiesInDbExist#cantReadTestDataUsingServiceInRequiredNew* is called, a completely new TestInstance of *ServiceTest5* is created using the  *TestInstanceFactory* implemented in *JUnit5Extension*, since the nested innerclass  *WhenSomeEntitiesInDbExist* has Lifecycle **PER_METHOD**.

That is not the case. Is that by design, or a bug in the release candidate?

Comment: Was the TestInstance of ServiceTest5 created through the TestInstanceFactory at all?

Comment: Here's a permalink for the example: https://github.com/1and1/ejb-cdi-unit/blob/772cb6dbbae13b1e11256afe8ad5b2a880234ce9/examples/ex1-1entity5/src/test/java/com/oneandone/ejbcdiunit/example1_5/ServiceTest5.java#L130

Comment: Yes, otherwise the working methods  would have no EntityManager or UserTransaction.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the inner class WhenSomeEntitiesInDbExist. Did it go through the factory?

Comment: No, only through postProcessTestInstance. The Factory does not create inner classes. I think the Interface would not work.

Comment: More discussion here: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1566